# What is the use of Windows for ARM installation disc?

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, iso-image, arm

I've seen some Russian putting official Microsoft's Windows for AArch64 ISOs online for download since Windows 10 version 2004.

[image: ARM64 ISO image]

Let's put legal issues aside, I am curious about the purpose of such ISOs.

As of now (the end of 2020), AArch64 based Windows devices are nowhere to be found, in my region at least. From what I've read, there are actually some, mostly laptops and tablet hybrids. But such devices always come with Windows 10 pre-installed and do not need the installation discs. I think they will likely have a separate ROM partition for "factory reset" function, so an installation disc is never needed.

Not to mention that ARM boards always have different logical hardware layout and require a specialized ROM image for each. Flashing an image of a device to a different device will result in a brick, even if they have the same CPU/chipset. So I do not see any purpose of a "universal" ISO like what we use on x86 PCs. I do not expect I can install such ISO on my Android TV box which has an ARM64 processor.

As Windows for ARM is pretty new, I do not have much information. Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*See update below!!!*

Microsoft provides ARM VHDX files so I guess the ISO files can also be used for ARM virtual machines

> With Windows 10 on ARM Insider Preview builds, you can create 64-bit ARM (ARM64) VMs in Hyper-V on Windows 10 ARM-based PCs. Creating ARM64 VMs is not supported on x64 hardware.
>
> Pre-requisites for creating ARM64 VMs:
>
> - A Windows 10 ARM-based PC with a Microsoft SQ1, Qualcomm Snapdragon 8cx, or Qualcomm Snapdragon 850 processor
> - Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise, build [19559](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) or newer
> - Hyper-V enabled ([instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v))
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewARM64?wa=wsignin1.0

If you don't have Hyper-V you can [run it on Qemu](https://winaero.com/install-windows-10-arm-qemu/). It can also be used to install on a [Raspberry](https://www.techradar.com/news/windows-10-on-arm-is-running-on-raspberry-pi-4-and-so-much-faster-than-pi-3) [Pi 3](https://discourse.pi64.win/t/how-to-installing-windows-10-arm64-17134-on-your-raspberry-pi-3-and-4/488/15), [Pi 4](https://www.windowslatest.com/2020/07/24/install-windows-10-on-raspberry-pi/), or a [Lumia 950 XL](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lumia-950-xl/windows-arm64-optimized-950-xl-testing-t4086951)

Winaero also said that it can be used to install from scratch, so it looks like there are some devices that can actually use that ISO

> Quickly after releasing [Windows build 20231](https://winaero.com/windows-10-build-20231-released-to-the-dev-channel/) to Dev Channel insiders, Microsoft also made available the ISO files for that build. So if you are interested in installing that build from scratch, you can save your time on building the ISO yourself.
>
> [Official Windows build 20231 ISO images are now available](https://winaero.com/official-windows-build-20231-iso-images-are-now-available/)

---

It turns out there's a standard called [Base System Architecture](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0094/a) from ARM which is extended by [Server Base System Architecture (SBSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Base_System_Architecture) and [Server Base Boot Requirements (SBBR)](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0044/e/?lang=en). They aim to standardize the way to boot on ARM systems. Once you have a motherboard with SBSA/SBBR support, you can boot any generic UEFI images of compliant OSes without doing anything special. That means **you can boot Windows ARM ISO image and install Windows natively on those platforms**

> Arm SystemReady SR (formerly Arm ServerReady) provides a solution for servers that Just Works, allowing partners to deploy Arm servers with confidence. The program is based on industry standards and the Server Base System Architecture (SBSA) and Server Base Boot Requirement (SBBR) supplements, alongside the Arm Server Architectural Compliance Suite (ACS). Arm SystemReady SR ensures that Arm-based servers work out of the box, offering seamless interoperability with standard operating systems, hypervisors, and software.
>
> https://developer.arm.com/architectures/platform-design/server-systems

In fact before SBSA Microsoft also [defined their own requirements in order for ARM systems to run Windows which also uses UEFI and ACPI](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/10/now-that-its-here-is-there-a-place-for-windows-rt/), and I guess you can also boot the ARM ISO on them

Despite "server" in the name, it's just a standard and anyone can implement it. It was even brought into Raspberry Pi 4

> The Pi 4 UEFI is aiming at full compliance with SBBR for running 64-bit Arm (AArch64 aka arm64) operating systems that are part of the ServerReady ecosystem. This includes stock FreeBSD, NetBSD, Microsoft Windows 10 and Linux distributions which boot via standard ACPI and expect an SBSA-compliant system. Arm ServerReady ensures that Arm-based infrastructure works out-of-the-box with off-the-shelf, offering seamless interoperability with standard operating systems, hypervisors, and software.
>
> [Raspberry Pi 4 Strides Towards ServerReady Status via SBBR-Compliant UEFI Firmware Effort](https://www.hackster.io/news/raspberry-pi-4-strides-towards-serverready-status-via-sbbr-compliant-uefi-firmware-effort-a6e390d5f019)

There are of course lots of ARM servers and workstations that support SBSA nowadays where the ARM ISO can be utilized

- [Avantek's Arm Workstation: Ampere eMAG 8180 32-core Arm64 Review](https://www.anandtech.com/show/15733/ampere-emag-system-a-32core-arm64-workstation)
- https://www.avantek.co.uk/arm-server-h270-t70/
- [Meet Qualcomm Centriq 2400, the world’s first 10-nanometer server processor](https://www.qualcomm.com/news/onq/2016/12/07/meet-qualcomm-centriq-2400-worlds-first-10-nanometer-server-processor)

They have UEFI setup just like x86:

[image: UEFI on ARM]

and you can see how they boot and show the Grub's multiboot menu here: https://youtu.be/6gpy5Hhj1C8?t=118

There's also a [Windows on ARM Server demo on Cavium ThunderX2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cp6YIqrFyQ)

See also

- [Design a System that “Just Works” - The Arm ServerReady Program and Beyond](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Arm%20Developer%20Community/PDF/ServerReady/Arm_ServerReady_White_Paper_Dec2019.pdf?revision=da739bd2-50e7-4bee-a73f-9d68968b2644)
- [ARM finally defines a platform as it sets its sights on the server room](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/01/arm-finally-defines-a-platform-as-it-sets-its-sights-on-the-server-room/)
- https://github.com/ARM-software/sbsa-acs

Comment: @Livy I updated the answer. The ARM ISO can be used to boot directly on systems with SBSA support

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the part about why the image is needed, as indeed the laptops/tablets come with Windows preinstalled and quite possibly with restore partitions as you say.

However, these machines are not the same as older Windows RT tablets, or Windows CE devices, where you need a separate, system-specific images.

These machines come with UEFI firmware and ACPI tables to describe/abstract the hardware. With a bit of fiddling, you can run reasonably standard Linux distributions on them too: https://github.com/aarch64-laptops/build

Answer (score -2):

ARM is a different type of processor architecture from the standard Intel x86 and 64-bit Intel architecture used on PCs today. (Even AMD produces chips that are compatible with Intel’s architecture.) Mobile devices like the iPhone, iPad, and Android phones—along with many other smaller devices—have ARM chips instead of Intel chips inside them.

Low-powered ARM PCs have some advantages over traditional x86 ones (which are most of the desktops and laptops we use today). ARM PCs have built-in LTE cellular connectivity, often offer better battery life than Intel and AMD CPUs, and the hardware is less expensive for manufacturers.

Microsoft would like Windows 10 to run on ARM hardware so it can reap those benefits. Sure, you probably won’t use an ARM desktop any time soon, but ARM could be a great choice for tablets, 2-in-1 convertibles, and even smaller laptops.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way. Did you even read the question? Who said the OP doesn't know about ARM? He asks about the ISO images because all the ARM laptops have Windows pre-installed and you can't plug a DVD or flash drive to install Windows on ARM from scratch